# Trying to get oldest file in entire directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the oldest file in the entire directory, but I keep getting the youngest. Is there something I am missing?

```
#gets oldest file
def get_oldest(value):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(value):
        current_it = os.path.getmtime(root)
        oldest_time = time.time()
        if current_it < oldest_time:
            oldest_time = current_it
    time_val = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(oldest_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return time_val

#gets youngest file
def get_youngest(value):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(value):
        current_it = os.path.getmtime(root)
        if current_it > 0:
            output = current_it
    time_val = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(output).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return time_val
```

Comment: Well, at first glance `current_it < oldest_time` is always going to be true since `oldest_time` is just `time.time()`... you don't really need `time.time()` to be honest, not sure why you are using it. The current time has nothing to do with which is the oldest file in the directory... just check the `mtime()` value and keep the lowest. Same goes for `current_it > 0` which is always true.

Comment: Try placing ```oldest_time = time.time()``` outside your loop.

Comment: Once I am done with the script I will implement what you both said, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_oldest(value):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(value):
        # this is modification time. you might have actually wanted
        # get ctime
        current_it = os.path.getmtime(root) 
        # this is now
        oldest_time = time.time()
        # this checks if the last modification time was before now,
        # which will almost always be true
        if current_it < oldest_time:
             # so this almost always happens
            oldest_time = current_it
    time_val = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(oldest_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return time_val
```

Since you are resetting `oldest_time` in each run of the loop, the last file visited by `os.walk` will be recorded as the "oldest", which is obviously not what you want. It's also worth noting that if there are no files at `value`, `oldest_time` will never be set, so `time_val =  ... oldest_time ...` will throw an error.

I think it's likely that you meant to say `oldest_time = time.time()` *above* the loop. That way, it is always set even if there are no files to be walked, and your comparison `if current_it < oldest_time:` does what you probably intended.

```py
def get_youngest(value):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(value):
        current_it = os.path.getmtime(root)
        # getmtime returns the number of seconds since
        # 0:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970, so it will always be
        # larger than 0 unless your system clock is very wrong
        if current_it > 0:
            # as such, this will happen on every iteration of the loop
            output = current_it
    time_val = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(output).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return time_val
```

Again, your output will simply be the last file visited, not the youngest. What you need to do is similar to what you needed to do with `get_oldest`. First, set `output` to `0` *above* the loop. Then, change your condition to `if current_it > output:`.